# is it ok to disable SuperFetch without SSD

Tags: windows, ssd, superfetch

Disabling SuperFetch causes Task Manager to report my disk as 100% usage.

It's really only at 10%. but I don't have a hard drive SDD and is it ok.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely nothing bad will happen if you disable it.

It won't massively improve matters either, most likely. At best it will reduce had drive activity during startup, but that's about it.